# MySQL Join Query 4 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to create a query with multiple joins, but it's not working for me.
I have the follow query statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.per_id 
              , s.per_key 
              , s.per_disabled 
              , p.acc_id 
              , a.acc_name 
              , p.approved_acc_id 
              , p.per_time 
           FROM acc_permissions p 
           JOIN svr_permissions s 
           JOIN acc_general a 
           JOIN svr_group_permissions g
          WHERE a.acc_id = p.acc_id 
            AND p.per_id = s.per_id 
             OR a.acc_per_group = g.group_id 
            AND a.acc_id = p.acc_id
```

Now if you don't want to examine this query, I understand so I will example my table structure;

First Table (includes users):

acc_general

Second table (includes permissions (linked to users)):

acc_permission
- This table includes rows that are linked to the acc_id in acc_general.
Multiple rows are possible for one unique acc_id in this table.

Third table (includes permissions (liked to groups)):

group_permissions

Now this includes rows that are linked to groups, each group has multiple rows in this table.

Inside acc_general there is a field called; acc_group_id, this is liked with the group_id inside group_permissions

So I need a query that returns all permissions from all players.
But it should not create duplicated permissions for a account.

So if I have an account that has a permission id 1 inside `acc_permission` and it has permission id 1 inside group_permissions it should ignore it.

It's hard to example, but i hope someone understands what I want.

Regards, Roel

Comment: You should fix your query in the query.  If you are using the `join` keyword (which I highly, highly recommend), then you should use the `on` clause for the conditions, rather than the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

`join` syntax for your query

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.per_id AS per_id,
       s.per_key AS per_key,
       s.per_disabled AS      per_disabled,
       p.acc_id AS acc_id, 
       a.acc_name as acc_name,
       p.approved_acc_id AS   approved_acc_id,
       p.per_time AS per_time 
from acc_permissions p 
join svr_permissions s 
ON p.per_id = s.per_id
join acc_general a 
ON a.acc_id= p.acc_id 
left join  svr_group_permissions g
ON a.acc_per_group = g.group_id
```

Comment: Ok this works almost, only the problem is, that when there are no results from svr_group_permissions, it doesnt show the results from acc_permissions, it only show results when both tables have rows selected.

Comment: @RoelSQL, you can have left join with these tables

Comment: Ok thx, I updated the query with your update, the left join at svr_group_permissions, but I still don't get any group permissions, however I do get the acc_permissions correct now.

Comment: @RoelSQL, you need to include column from svr_group_permissions in the select list

Comment: Okey, the problem is the column in my svr_group_permissions is also per_key, because all this query should do is returning all permissions keys from a player that are linked via acc_permissions and svr_group_permissions, can it be that it is because from acc_permissions p, I mean svr_group_permissions is linked to acc_general
I'm sorry but im just really lost here..

Comment: I have to following
     SELECT 
       p.acc_id AS acc_id, 
       a.acc_name as acc_name,
       p.approved_acc_id AS   approved_acc_id,
       p.per_time AS per_time 
from acc_general a
left join acc_permissions p 
ON a.acc_id = p.acc_id
left join  svr_group_permissions g
ON a.acc_per_group = g.group_id

And everything came out correctly but now I need to add svr_permissions to get the permission data, but it should affect my results, per_id is inside acc_permissions and inside svr_group_permissions and is the primary key of svr_permissions

Comment: @RoelSQL, probably this is what you need at the end left join svr_permissions s 
ON p.per_id = s.per_id
AND g.per_id = s.per_id

Comment: RADAR, I think I almost have it;
I have to following:
 SELECT per_key AS per_key,
       p.acc_id AS acc_id, 
       a.acc_name as acc_name,
       p.approved_acc_id AS   approved_acc_id,
       p.per_time AS per_time 
from acc_general a
left join (acc_permissions p, svr_permissions s)
ON a.acc_id = p.acc_id AND s.per_id = p.per_id
left join (svr_group_permissions g, svr_permissions s2)
ON a.acc_per_group = g.group_id AND s2.per_id = p.per_id`

Comment: But I get the error:
Column 'per_key' in field list is ambiguous
How can I ignore this error? Because i want only 1 field result per_key if I add both it always is NULL , key or key , NULL
And sorry to say but I really hate this comment system lol.

Comment: Never mind it still was not working as it should, it seems not possible so I guess I will have to make different queries in my program to get the result I want, thanks for trying to help me anyway!

Comment: have this instead, SELECT IFNULL(p.per_key, s.per_key) AS per_key,